# Motivation for continuous extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Hi I have to prove as one of the exercises continuous extension theorem first in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space and then in general metric space. I am struggling to flesh out the problem first and motivate proof. I know Tietze extension theorem addresses this question, but I want to tackle it myself first.

If f is a real continuous function on a closed set $ E\subset \mathbb{R}^1 $ prove there exists continuous real function $g:\mathbb{R}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^1 s.t. \forall x\in E \space g(x)=f(x) $; extend the theorem to any metric space.

I can see that if we drop the assumption for closed set, the continuous function on a not closed set can result in an unbounded image and then for any candidate function $g:\mathbb{R}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^1$ will have discontinuity at the limit points of $E$.

For example function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ defined on a set $(0,1)$. From here I conclude that boundness is essential part of the solution. Is this right starting point? There must be something about closed set leading to bounded images of continuous functions? Could someone help me with the direction/motivation?

Hugely appreciate any help.